# In OS X 10.10.2 the Finder's Preview function is not working

Tags: macos, finder, quicklook

In OS X 10.10.2 the Finder's Preview function is not working. If I select some image or pdf files I cannot see file's preview and only see wait logo. How can I fix these error?

I found some solution about qlmanage. [Fixing Quick Look issues in OS X](http://www.cnet.com/news/fixing-quick-look-issues-in-os-x/) This can clear and rebuild the thumbnail's caches, however this program hung and did not finish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From: [Easy fix for Mac Finder preview thumnails not displaying](http://www.jgoode.com/easy-fix-for-mac-finder-preview-thumbnails-not-displaying/)

Delete all from your `home > library > preferences`. Delete all: `com.apple.finder.plist`

Proceed with logout and then login again.

Tried it, it should work!